# Ubuntu 15.10 - Crashes when plugging external monitor (Asus ux501jw-dh71)

Tags: drivers, 15.10, external-monitor

Just got a new Asus ux501jw-dh71 laptop. As soon as I plug a monitor my display crashes and all I can do is open a terminal with ctrl-alt-fx to reboot. I have tried different nvidia drivers (352 and 355) and I end up with the same result. Tried with different monitors, still same result. All external monitors are not 4k monitors compared to the laptop's built in display. Everything works on Windows, so it's not a cable issue.

Does anyone know how I could fix this or where to look (log file) to see what's happening?

Comment: The same issue happened for me too. Mine is asus ux303lb. Still don't know that is the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around - having this same issue on 14.04 on my Asus UX303LA(B) -- The workaround posted here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1188772  -- appears to have worked for me.

### (Switching to 'uxa' for the AccelMethod in xorg.conf/20-intel.conf) --  I will update here in a few days to see if it resolved permanently.

```
   Edit:     /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf


Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option     "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option      "AIGLX" "on"
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
        Option      "Composite" "Enable"
EndSection
```

---

```
root@lappy ~ # cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS \n \l

root@lappy ~ # uname -a
Linux lappy 4.2.0-34-generic #39~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 11:38:02 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

Lots of other references to the actual error in Dmesg:

```
[14257.151579] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 27541 at /build/linux-lts-wily-MVxxD8/linux-lts-wily-4.2.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:1365 assert_plane.constprop.96+0x73/0xa0 [i915]()
[14257.151581] plane A assertion failure (expected on, current off)
```

Other Similar / Possible dupes:

```
on kernel.org bugzilla -- bug:  103771
on launchpad -- xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1436590
on launchpad -- linux/+bug/1465506
```

Comment: nope! didn't even stay fixed for 24 hours. Trying the upstream kernel > 4.5.0 next.

Comment: Nope :-(   4.5.0-040500-generic  still has the same issue. Bum deal.